# JAVA - can't call my array method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, call

Eclipse says: 'chiffres cannot be resolved to  a variable', how to fix the call method  ?

```
public class Table {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Tableau1 table = new Tableau1();


    table.CreerTable();
    table.AfficherTable(chiffres);

}}
```

part:
and class Tableau1 with array: to declare it

```
public class Tableau1 {
int [][] chiffres;
int nombre;
public void CreerTable(){

    int[][] chiffres= {{11,01,3},
                        {12,02,4},
                        {12,03,5}};
    //edited
    this.chiffres=chiffres;


}

public int[][] AfficherTable(int[][] chiffres){
    this.nombre=12;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){

    System.out.println("essai"+chiffres[i][1]);
    if(chiffres[i][0]==nombre){System.out.println("ma ligne ="+chiffres[i][0]+","+chiffres[i][1]+","+chiffres[i][2]);
                                };

                        }
                        return chiffres;
}
```

}

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, what is it and where it is declared ?

Comment: sorry I pasted twice

Comment: Did you forget to declare the variable "chiffres"? I don't see it anywhere in your main method.

Comment: @chris_cx Variables needs to declare, before using them. Where you declared it in your code ?

Comment: Is that your full code?! I don't see any declaration of chiffres?! Is it the type in Tableau1?! Or it is a class?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    table.CreerTable();
    table.AfficherTable(chiffres);
```

By resolving chiffres it searches in the Class Table as you don't specify that chiffres comes from Tableau1.
Therefore the solution is:

```
    table.CreerTable();
    table.AfficherTable(table.chiffres);
```

Comment: `this.chiffres=chiffres;`

Answer (score 7):

You have 3 problems here.

**Problem 1 :**

1) You method  `AfficherTable(chiffres)` need not to pass an argument, since it is an instance member.

You can simply call

```
table.AfficherTable();
```

That solves your problem.

Before doing that problem no 2

**Problem 2:**

2) You delcared `chifferes` as a instance member `int [][] chiffres;`

and you are initializing it's in constructor

```
public void CreerTable(){

    int[][] chiffres= {{11,01,3},
                        {12,02,4},
                        {12,03,5}};

}
```

But if you closely look, you are creating new array again. That won't work, since you are creating new array and forgot your instance member.

Change your constructor to

```
public void CreerTable(){

        chiffres= new  int[3][3] {{11,01,3},
                            {12,02,4},
                            {12,03,5}};

    }
```

**Problem 3 :**

After changing that constructor, since you are using it in the same class member, you need not to receive it. Hence you change your method declaration as

```
public int[][] AfficherTable(){
```

You'll be fine I guess now.

Comment: thanks, there is easier solution, but i will test yours, for future

Answer (score 1):

chiffers is neither a local variable of the main method, nor a field of the class **Table**,  that's why the error.